# Explanation of proxy_association to find unassociated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I came across some magic today and I am hoping for some help in understanding it so I can write informed code.

In my app, I have three classes:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :selected_apps
  has_many :app_profiles, through: :selected_apps do
    def unselected(reload=false)
      @unselected_app_profiles = nil if reload
      @unselected_app_profiles ||= proxy_association.owner.app_profile_ids.empty? ?
        AppProfile.all :
        AppProfile.where("id NOT IN (?)", proxy_association.owner.app_profile_ids)
    end
  end
end

class AppProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class SelectedApp < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :app_profile
end
```

The above code lets me do `person.app_profiles.unselected` and get back all of the `AppProfiles` that are not currently associated with the `Person` without having to do a lot of SQL work. Brilliant!

My problem is that I don't *understand* the code - which always leaves me feeling unsettled. I tried trolling through the proxy_association documentation, but it was fairly opaque.

Can anyone provide a reasonably straight-forward explanation and/or a good place to learn more?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, when you call `self` while extending an `association` it won't return an `Association` instance, but instead delegates to `to_a`.

Try it:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :app_profiles, through: :selected_apps do
    def test_me
      self
    end
  end
end
```

Sometimes we need to get to the actual `association` object while were extending the association itself. Enter the [`proxy_association` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83e42d52e37a33682fcac856330fd5d06e5a529c/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L60), which will give us the `association` which contains the [`owner`, `target`, and `reflection` attributes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/90d96353e6dcd962b182e03f53f2214acde00907/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb#L21).

For reference here is the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+extensions).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997266/custom-association-method-can-this-be-done/9087086#9087086) provides a simpler use case of `proxy_association.owner`.

Comment: Thank you, Azolo! Helpful post and links - I'll be studying up... Cheers