# conditionally retrieve records in a has_many through extend method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out how to conditionally retrieve records in a has_many through association.

I have three classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_associations
  has_many :projects,
           source: :user_associatable,
           source_type: 'Project',
           through: :user_associations do
    def owned
      # retrieve projects that have is_owner = true on the user_association
    end
  end
end

class UserAssociations < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_associatable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_associations, as: :user_associatable
  has_many :users, through: :user_associations
end
```

`UserAssociation` has a polymorphic association to `Project` for added complexity.

When I run `User.first.projects.owned` I only want to retrieve projects that are associated to the user through `UserAssociations` that have the `is_owner` boolean set to `true`.

I'm guessing I have to do something with `proxy_association`?

Comment: have you seen this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997266/custom-association-method-can-this-be-done/9087086#9087086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you just need a `where` clause within the `owned` method: `where("users_associations.is_owner": true)`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you! I didn't realise `user_associations` is already in included in the ActiveRecord build statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by specifying a scope on your project class and using that scope in your has_many in your user class.

In your user class...

```
has_many :projects,
           source: :user_associatable,
           source_type: 'Project',
           through: :user_associations,
           -> { is_owner }
```

in your project class...

```
  scope :is_owner, where('is_owner = true')
```

Comment: Interesting take, I wasn't aware to can extend a has_many association like that. However `is_owner` is not on the Project model but on the UserAssociation model.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a scope in project model

```
scope :owned, -> {where(user_authentications: {is_owner: true})}
```

Comment: Not sure this will work, the way I intend. `User.first.owned` will return the associations, not the project, and considering the project is polymorpically associated I would need to also specify the `user_associatable_type` in the `user_associations` condition.

Comment: sorry it should be in Project model it will be like User.first.projects.owned

Comment: Yeah that would work, I'm going with Andy's answer though, because it's contained within the user model relation, i.e. `Project.owned` shouldn't be a method.